# How can I use maven-assembly-plugin package jar include source code？

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

How can I use maven-assembly-plugin package jar include source code？
It is my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>base</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/resources/assembly/api.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It is my api.xml

```
<assembly>
    <id>api</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <baseDirectory>com\kuakao\base</baseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}\target\base\WEB-INF\classes\com\kuakao\base\api</directory>   
            <outputDirectory>/api</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

How can I use maven-assembly-plugin package jar include source code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really just have to add class and source files from a specific package, then you just have to add the source dir to another fileset:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>${project.basedir}\src\main\java\com\kuakao\base\api</directory>   
    <outputDirectory>/api-source</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

Maybe also have a look at [maven-source-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html)